# Разгруппировать элементы в Inkscape

Tags: svg, inkscape

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В данном случаи, все 4 элемента как 1 целое. Каким образом в Inkscape возможно выполнить так, чтобы каждый из 4 элементов был как 1, то есть разделить и работать с каждым по отдельности.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 5.3 5.3499999" version="1.1" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  <path d="M 0.36,0 C 0.16,0 0,0.16 0,0.37 V 0.39 C 0,0.6 0.15,0.77 0.36,0.77 H 4.93 C 5.13,0.77 5.3,0.6 5.3,0.39 V 0.37 C 5.3,0.17 5.14,0 4.93,0 Z m 2.26,1.54 c -0.2,0 -0.37,0.16 -0.37,0.37 0,0.2 0.15,0.37 0.37,0.37 H 4.93 C 5.13,2.28 5.3,2.12 5.3,1.91 5.3,1.71 5.14,1.54 4.93,1.54 Z m 0,1.52 c -0.2,0 -0.37,0.16 -0.37,0.37 v 0.01 c 0,0.2 0.15,0.37 0.37,0.37 H 4.93 C 5.13,3.81 5.3,3.65 5.3,3.44 V 3.43 C 5.3,3.23 5.14,3.06 4.93,3.06 Z M 0.36,4.59 C 0.16,4.59 0,4.75 0,4.96 v 0 c 0,0.2 0.15,0.37 0.36,0.37 h 4.57 c 0.2,0 0.37,-0.16 0.37,-0.37 v 0 C 5.3,4.76 5.14,4.59 4.93,4.59 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: "Разгруппировать" подразумевает, что это группа. Если это действительно группа - использовать соответствующую команду "разгруппировать" в меню или на панели инструментов.

Comment: Не выходит, оно возможно не сгруппировано, а как одно целое. Возможно ли разделить элементы в данном случаи?

Comment: Если это один контур, то меню Path (Контур) - Split path (или Brake apart)

Comment: Блин, у меня все на русском, не могу найти...

Comment: У меня в меню Контур ниже пункта Разбить, называется Split path (этот пункт не локализован). P.S. пункт "разбить" у меня тоже разделяет этот объект на 4 части.

Comment: Изменил скриншет, по всей видимости у меня нету данного пункта. Как я могу его добавить?

Comment: Пункт "Разбить". Тот пункт, про который я сначала писал, разбивает не пересекающиеся контуры. "Разбить" разделит в том числе и пересекающиеся.

Comment: Круто, работает

Answer (score 2):

Пути четырех полосок Соединены в один общий путь.
Каждый путь для каждой полоски начинается с команды - ***"m"***

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы разделить один путь на четыре отдельных пути, запишите команды вот так:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 5.5 5.3" version="1.1" style="width:100px;height:100px" id="svg4">
  <path d="M.4 0C.2 0 0 .2 0 .4s.1.4.4.4h4.5c.2 0 .4-.2.4-.4S5.1 0 4.9 0Z" />
  <path d="M2.6 1.5c-.2 0-.3.2-.3.4s.1.4.3.4H5a.4.4 0 1 0 0-.8Z" />
  <path d="M2.6 3c-.2 0-.3.2-.3.4s.1.4.3.4H5c.2 0 .4-.1.4-.4 0-.2-.2-.3-.4-.3Z" />
  <path d="M.4 4.6c-.2 0-.4.2-.4.4s.1.3.4.3h4.5c.2 0 .4-.1.4-.3 0-.2-.2-.4-.4-.4Z" />
</svg>
```

Либо воспользуйтесь командой Inkscape - **Контур / Разбить**